# What's the state of the art for matrix nuclear/trace norm optimization

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, sparse-matrix, convex-optimization

I am interested in simple matrix optimizations with nuclear/trace norm:

$\min_X \left(f(X) + \|X\|_*\right)$

where $\|X\|_*$ stands for the trace norm of the matrix $X$, and $f$ is a convex smooth function.

What is the largest size of the matrix that the state-of-the-art solvers can handle?  In particular, I am interested in the case where *both* the number of rows *and* columns are large.

Comment: Please use LaTeX for math (like I just did).